# How to set isAdmin variable in passport local strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to create a middleware to allow only admin access to certain routes in my node.js project. My middleware currently looks like this.

```
    function adminAuth(req, res, next){
  if(req.user.isAdmin){
    return next();
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
}
```

The issue is that req.user.isAdmin is never recognized even if the user data contains isAdmin: true. I believe that I need to define user.isAdmin in my passport strategy but I am not sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

here is my local strategy

```
  (async function addUser() {
    let client;
    try {
      client = await MongoClient.connect(url);

      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const col = db.collection('users');

      const user = await col.findOne({ email });

      debug('Found user by email');
      debug(user);
      if (!user) {
        req.flash('error', 'The username or password is wrong');
        done(null, false);
      } else {
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (match) {
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          req.flash('error', 'The username or password is wrong');
          // we pass null because it did not error, just failed
          done(null, false);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debug(e.stack);
    }

    client.close();
  }());
}


));
};
```

Here is my passport.js

```
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.email);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((email, done) => {
    done(null, email);
  });
};
```

Comment: check the req object contain the user object ? 
your local strategy looks fine...

Comment: `isAdmin` is _not_ a passport concept, whatever user object you return as part of `deserializeUser` is what passport will return. So unless that object _has_ an `isAdmin` property then it won't magically appear because you are using Passport.

Comment: @James could you explain a bit further? I am a bit new at this. I edited my question to contain my deserializeUser

Comment: @klaurtar whatever you return from `deserializeUser` is what becomes `req.user` - at the minute, you return an email address, if you need more information then you need to return this.